# add and remove values from array in vue js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

i have code below that pushes values to an array structured as **array: [{ Details: '', unt: '', prc: '' },],** and in my code i want to get result of multiplication of *unt* and *prc* and get the sum of them as done in methods in below code ... my problem is whenever i click on delete button the **totalAmount** is not being updated where i can see in function **deletee** that index has been removed successfully but total is not changing .. is there a way to solve this?

```js
data() {
    return {
      arrayDetails: '',
      arrayunt: '',
      arrayprc: '',
      array: [{
        Details: '',
        unt: '',
        prc: ''
      }, ],
      gettot: '',
      totalAmount: [],
    },
  },
  computed: {
    alltot() {
      this.gettot = this.arrayunt * this.arrayprc;
      this.totalAmount.push(this.gettot);
      return this.totalAmount;
    }

  },
  methods: {
    deletee(index) {
      this.array.splice(this.array.indexOf(index));
    },
    sumArray(arr) {
      return arr.reduce((total, num) => total + num, 0);
    },

    add() {
      JSON.stringify(this.array);


      this.array.push({
        Details: this.arrayDetails,
        unt: this.arrayunt,
        prc: this.arrayprc
      });

    },
  };
```

```html
<div class="row mt-4">
  <div class="col">
    <p> details</p>
    <textarea class="paid-input" v-model="arrayDetails"></textarea>

  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>quantity</p>
    <textarea class="paid-input" v-model="arrayunt" type="number"> </textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <p> unit price</p>
    <textarea class="paid-input" v-model="arrayprc" type="number"></textarea>

  </div>

  <div class="col-1 mt-5">
    <button @click="add" class="btn btn-danger" style="padding: 15px;">Add </button>
  </div>


</div>


<td scope="row">
  <pre v-for="(array, i) in array" :key="i" v-show="i>0">{{ i }}<button type="button" class="btn btn-link"  @click="deletee(i)" style="color: rgb(74, 74, 255); text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer ; font-size: 15px; "> Delete</button></pre>
</td>
<td>
  <pre v-for="(array, i) in array" :key="i">{{ array.Details }}</pre>
</td>

<td>
  <pre v-for="(array, i) in array" :key="i">{{ array.unt }}</pre>
</td>
<td>
  <pre v-for="(array, i) in array" :key="i">{{ array.prc }}</pre>
</td>
<td>
  <pre style="    margin-top: 15px;" v-for="(array, i) in array" :key="i" v-show="Number(array.unt) * Number(array.prc) > 0"> {{ Number(array.unt) * Number(array.prc) }}$  </pre>
</td>


<div class="col">
  <p><b>Total Amount</b> </p>
  <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: white; border: 1 px solid black; border-radius: 10px; height: 79px;">

    <h6><b>{{ sumArray(totalAmount) }}$</b></h6>

  </div>
```

Comment: `methods:` is not inside the object you're returning.

Comment: @Barmar question edited .. methods are inside objects

Comment: You're not changing totalAmount anywhere but add(), so it's not expected to change in delete(). Since it depends on array, it probably should be a computed instead

Comment: @EstusFlask when i put it inside computed is shows me error of side effect

Comment: What did you try? It surely shouldn't if implemented correctly

Comment: @EstusFlask i edited code above

Comment: The error is because you shouldn't mutate anything inside a computed, you don't need totalAmount at all, should be something like `alltot() { return this.array.reduce(...)` that takes prc and unt array fields into account the way you need it.

Comment: There seems to be a missing `{}` around the whole object. I saw the `data()` function and thought everything should be inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would name your variables more appropriately. A state variable with the name `array` makes the code harder to understand. Changing it to `items` adds a little more context. Same goes for your input fields.

The code below works for adding and removing items. Use methods when possible. Please note that storing the item totals in another array adds unnecessary complexity. Now you need to manage parallel arrays and this makes the code harder to maintain. See the cleaned-up example at the bottom of this post.

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      itemDetails: '',
      itemQuantity: '',
      itemPrice: '',
      items: [],
      totalAmount: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatCurrency(value) {
      return value.toLocaleString('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: 'USD'
      });
    },
    removeItem(index) {
      this.items.splice(index, 1);
      this.totalAmount.splice(index, 1);
    },
    sumArray(arr) {
      return this.formatCurrency(arr.reduce((total, num) => total + num, 0));
    },
    add() {
      this.items.push({
        details: this.itemDetails,
        quantity: Number(this.itemQuantity),
        price: Number(this.itemPrice)
      });
      this.totalAmount.push(this.itemQuantity * this.itemPrice);
      this.itemDetails = '';
      this.itemQuantity = '';
      this.itemPrice = '';
    },
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container">
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col">
      <label>Details</label>
      <input class="paid-input" v-model="itemDetails" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label>Quantity</label>
      <input class="paid-input" v-model="itemQuantity" type="number" />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label>Unit price</label>
      <input class="paid-input" v-model="itemPrice" type="number" />
    </div>
    <div class="col mt-3">
      <button @click="add" class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Details</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Item Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">
          <pre v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">{{ i + 1 }}<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" @click="removeItem(i)" style="color:rgb(74,74,255); text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer; font-size:15px">Remove</button></pre>
        </td>
        <td>
          <pre v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">{{ item.details }}</pre>
        </td>
        <td>
          <pre v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">{{ item.quantity }}</pre>
        </td>
        <td>
          <pre v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">{{ item.price }}</pre>
        </td>
        <td>
          <pre style="margin-top:15px" v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" v-show="item.quantity * item.price > 0"> {{ formatCurrency(item.quantity * item.price) }}  </pre>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="col">
    <label class="fw-bold">Total Amount:</label> <span>{{ sumArray(totalAmount) }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

## A cleaner approach

Here is a better way to handle the state. Instead of keeping track of a separate total array, you could compute the total of all the items.

I also pre-loaded the items so that removing can be accomplished without first adding items.

```js
const { createApp, onMounted } = Vue;

const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      itemDetails: '',
      itemQuantity: '',
      itemPrice: '',
      items: [
        { details: 'Tie', quantity: 2, price:  8.50 },
        { details: 'Pants', quantity: 1, price: 12.25 },
        { details: 'Socks', quantity: 3, price:  4.25 }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.detailsRef.focus(); // Initial focus
  },
  methods: {
    formatCurrency(value) {
      return currencyFormatter.format(value);
    },
    removeItem(index) {
      this.items.splice(index, 1);
    },
    displayTotal(arr) {
      return this.formatCurrency(arr.reduce((sum, { quantity, price }) =>
        sum + (quantity * price), 0));
    },
    submit(e) {
      // Add item
      this.items.push({
        details: this.itemDetails,
        quantity: Number(this.itemQuantity),
        price: Number(this.itemPrice)
      });
      // Clear form
      this.itemDetails = '';
      this.itemQuantity = '';
      this.itemPrice = '';
      // Reset focus
      this.$refs.detailsRef.focus();
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container">
  <form class="row mt-4" @submit.prevent="submit">
    <div class="col">
      <label for="item-details-input">Details</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="item-details-input"
        placeholder="Item description..."
        v-model="itemDetails"
        ref="detailsRef"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label for="item-quantity-input">Quantity</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="item-quantity-input"
        placeholder="Enter a quantity..."
        v-model="itemQuantity"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <label for="item-price-input">Unit price</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="item-price-input"
        placeholder="Enter a price..."
        v-model="itemPrice"
        required
      />
    </div>
    <div class="col mt-3">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Add</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <hr />
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="text-start">Position</th>
        <th class="text-start">Details</th>
        <th class="text-end">Quantity</th>
        <th class="text-end">Unit Price</th>
        <th class="text-end">Item Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
        <td scope="row">
          {{ i + 1 }}
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-link text-decoration-underline cursor-pointer"
            style="color: rgb(74, 74, 255)"
            @click="removeItem(i)"
          >
            Remove
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>{{ item.details }}</td>
        <td class="text-end">{{ item.quantity }}</td>
        <td class="text-end">{{ formatCurrency(item.price) }}</td>
        <td class="text-end">
          {{ formatCurrency(item.price * item.quantity) }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <hr />
  <div class="col">
    <span class="fw-bold">Total Amount: </span>
    <span>{{ displayTotal(items) }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thank you .. that's was very helpful!

Comment: @ezgi95 I added a cleaner example of your Vue code at the bottom of this post.